# Firebase realtime database object value type

Tags: java, arrays, firebase-realtime-database

1. I want to save an array of string into firebase object. When I tried to make the path on the realtime database, the value must not be blank. But I don't know what I should put into the path to save it in the realtime database.

   This is what it looks like

   [image: This is what it looks like.]
2. Can someone give a link or any example on saving array of string into the firebase RTDB object?

I tried to input number and letters into the firebase RTDB object but I still can't save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, please read [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) as trying to store arrays in Firebase is a common anti-pattern.

---

If you want to store an array in a node in the Firebase console, paste the array as the value. So `["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"]`.

---

If you want to make an array item by item in the Firebase console, enter the array indices as they keys. So:

- key: "0" (note the quotes, all keys are strings)
  value: "Item1"
- key: "1"
  value: "Item2"
- key: "2"
  value: "Item3"

---

Comment: What is the meaning of common anti-pattern? If I put ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"], does it mean only 3 item could be stored? Or could I add another item?

Comment: First off: did you read the blog post I linked? That explains quite well why using arrays is not commonly recommended on Firebase Realtime Database.

Comment: Yes I read it. But I just don't get the definition or meaning of common anti-pattern.

Comment: Without a more specific question, it's unlikely that we can explain it better than that classic article does (really, it's one of the top-visited posts on the blog). Why can't you use the Firebase Realtime Database's primitive `push()`  operations for your lists of data?