# How to get the last data on firebase onDataChange?

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the last input data from firebase. But by using the ValueListener and onDataChange, the value that I got is the last data-1 (previous of the last).

This is the code:

```
mDose1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
       int iDose = snapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
    }
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
       throw error.toException();
    }

});
```

I couldn't find any ways to solve this by searching on the interner, or i might not understand of what I should search.

//Edit

The real issue isn't with the ValueListener. The iDose could get the last data. But then when I add the iDose to an arrayList, the arrayList willprint the previous data. Why my arrayList get the previous data first?

This is the code:

```
mDose1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
       int iDose = snapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
       Sting sDose = String.valueof(iDose1);
       jud.setText(sDose);
       arrayList.add(iDose);
    }
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
       throw error.toException();
    }

});
```

The `jud.setText(sDose);` works fine by showing the last data. But the arrayList keeps showing the previous data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the arrayList not keeping the first data, the code need to be change like this:

```
mDose1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
       int iDose = snapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
       Sting sDose = String.valueof(iDose1);
       arrayListA.add(sDose);
       arrayListB.add(arrayListA.remove(0));
    }
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
       throw error.toException();
    }

});
```

Then I print the `arrayListB.get(n)` from n = 1 then it works fine.
I tried to print the `arrayListA.get(n)` from n = 1, but it won't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this code on Android **and** have caching enabled, it is expected that your `onDataChange` will first (pretty much instantly) get called with the value from the cache.

If the device has a connection to the server and if the value on the server has changed your `onDataChange` will be called again with the value from the server.

---

If that is not the behavior you get, please edit your question to show what actually happens (for example by printing the offending value). That's also a good moment to implement `onCancelled`, which at its minimum should be:

```
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    throw error.toException();
}
```

Comment: I left the onCancelled as blank. But I've add the "throw error.toException();". Then how to not read the value from cache?

Comment: I know what should I do when someone answers my question. I've marked your answer as the answer on the other question by me  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77346632/firebase-realtime-database-object-value-type/77346661?noredirect=1#comment136357466_77346661.  What do you expect? Any wrongdoings by me?

Comment: Did you read the rest of my comment and the link I provided?

Comment: Yes, I read all of them. I got the point for the cache. You said to consider using get, but the listener is what I need. Then?

Comment: If you use a listener, your `onDataChange` will first be called with the value from the cache, and then later with the value from the server (if that value is different),. There is no way to change this behavior.

Comment: Have you read my answer on this question? I made the code to read last value with listener by removing first data `n[0]` then add the fist arrayList into another arrayList.  The second arrayList will store the data without the value from cache.

Comment: Now my code works fine using listener and removing the first value from cache.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working @Abisay 